# SQL subquery with GROUP BY that returns duplicate minimums. how is this interpreted by outer query?

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I was working through some subquery questions and code below was provided as the answer.

my question:
if the inner query returns two minimum salaries that are the same, but belong to different departments. how will the outer query interpet this? will it recognize that salaries refer to different departments?

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, salary, department_id 
FROM employees 
WHERE salary IN ( SELECT MIN(salary) 
FROM employees 
GROUP BY department_id );
```

thank you

Comment: What is your sample data and expected output?

Comment: Hi Suraj, I was attempting question number 3 on this webpage. https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-subqueries-exercises.php#SQLEDITOR

Comment: This won't do as you want. For example. If the minimum salary in DeptA is 50k then it will return all employees with 50K salary even if they are in a different department

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not know anything about the department information. You need to change the IN  to a JOIN:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, e.salary, e.department_id 
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN ( SELECT department_id,IN(salary)  AS salary
FROM employees 
GROUP BY department_id) s
ON s.department_id=e.department_id
AND s.salary=e.salary;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the statement is currently written it is going to show you each record from employees table which matches the minimum salary for each department with the salary itself. So, the outer query doesn't know anything about the department_id, meaning that there is no correlation between this attribute from the inner query with the outer query at all. You would need to change your logic for example to a JOIN to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rank()` :

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, rank() over (partition by e.department_id order by e.salary) as seq
      from employees e
     ) e
where e.seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass additional information/condition like this for the department.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    empname VARCHAR(20)
    ,salary DECIMAL(18, 2)
    ,department_id INT
    )

INSERT INTO employees
VALUES ('A', 100,1), ('B', 100, 2), ('C', 300, 2)

SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE salary IN (
        SELECT MIN(salary)
        FROM employees
        GROUP BY department_id
        HAVING department_id = 2
        )
    AND department_id = 2;
```

Here is the output

```
empname salary  department_id
-----------------------------
B       100.00  2
```

Although, `100.00` is the minimum salary for both `A` and `B`, but you have passed information for department id: `2`. So, only `B` has come in the output.